# POST with HTTPBuilder -> NullPointerException?

Tags: grails, post, groovy, httpbuilder

I'm trying to make a simple HTTP POST request, and I have no idea why the following is failing. I tried following the examples [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/post.html), and I don't see where I'm going wrong.

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate.setBody(HTTPBuilder.java:1131)
    ...
```

**Code**

```
def List<String> search(String query, int maxResults)
{
    def http = new HTTPBuilder("mywebsite")

    http.request(POST) {
        uri.path = '/search/'
        body = [string1: "", query: "test"]
        requestContentType = URLENC

        headers.'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 Ubuntu/8.10 Firefox/3.0.4'

        response.success = { resp, InputStreamReader reader ->
            assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200

            String data = reader.readLines().join()

            println data
        }
    }
    []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
    http.request(POST) {
        uri.path = '/search/'

        send URLENC, [string1: "", string2: "heroes"]
```

Answer (score 21):

I've found it's necessary to set the content type before assigning the body.  This works for me, using groovy 1.7.2:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.0' )
import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*

def List<String> search(String query, int maxResults)
{
    def http = new HTTPBuilder("mywebsite")

    http.request(POST) {
        uri.path = '/search/'
        requestContentType = URLENC
        headers.'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 Ubuntu/8.10 Firefox/3.0.4'
        body = [string1: "", query: "test"]

        response.success = { resp, InputStreamReader reader ->
            assert resp.statusLine.statusCode == 200

            String data = reader.readLines().join()

            println data
        }
    }
    []
}
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. Using `send URLENC, [string1: "", string2: "heroes"]` will also work, but makes it harder to unit test when mocking HTTPBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to execute a POST with contentType JSON and pass a complex json data, try to convert your body manually:

```
def attributes = [a:[b:[c:[]]], d:[]] //Complex structure
def http = new HTTPBuilder("your-url")
http.auth.basic('user', 'pass') // Optional
http.request (POST, ContentType.JSON) { req ->
  uri.path = path
  body = (attributes as JSON).toString()
  response.success = { resp, json -> }
  response.failure = { resp, json -> }
}
```