# Groovy HTTPBuilder and Jackson

Tags: json, groovy, jackson, httpbuilder

Can I use Jackson instead of JSON-lib with Groovy's HTTPBuilder when setting the body on request?

Example:

```
client.request(method){
      uri.path = path
      requestContentType = JSON

      body = customer

      response.success = { HttpResponseDecorator resp, JSONObject returnedUser ->

        customer = getMapper().readValue(returnedUser.content[0].toString(), Customer.class)
        return customer
      }
}
```

In this example, I'm using Jackson fine when handling the response, but I believe the request is using JSON-lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  To use another JSON library to parse incoming JSON on the response, set the content type to `ContentType.TEXT` and set the Accept header manually, as in this example: http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/contentTypes.html.  You'll receive the JSON as text, which you can then pass to Jackson.

To set JSON encoded output on a POST request, just set request body as a string after you've converted it with Jackson.  Example:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.1' )

import groovyx.net.http.*

new HTTPBuilder('http://localhost:8080/').request(Method.POST) {
    uri.path = 'myurl'
    requestContentType = ContentType.JSON
    body = convertToJSONWithJackson(payload)

    response.success = { resp ->
        println "success!"
    }
}
```

Also note that when posting, [you have to set the `requestContentType` before setting the body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823590/post-with-httpbuilder-nullpointerexception/2859135#2859135).

Comment: Thanks.  I doing something similar on the response, but I'm talking about marshalling the body.  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of manually setting headers and calling the method with the wrong ContentType as suggested in the accepted answer, It would be cleaner and easier to overwrite the parser for `application/json`.

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder()
http.parser.'application/json' = http.parser.'text/plain'
```

This will cause JSON responses to be handled in the same manner that plain text is handled.  The plain text handler gives you an `InputReader` along with the `HttpResponseDecorator`.  To use Jackson to bind the response to your class, you just need to use an `ObjectMapper`:

```
http.request( GET, JSON ) {

    response.success = { resp, reader ->
        def mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        mapper.readValue( reader, Customer.class )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to the party, but now you can do this in a cleaner way, specially in places with too many HTTP calls, e.g. in tests (example is for [Spock](http://spockframework.org/)):

```
def setup() {
    http = configure {
        request.uri = "http://localhost:8080"
        // Get your mapper from somewhere
        Jackson.mapper(delegate, mapper, [APPLICATION_JSON])
        Jackson.use(delegate, [APPLICATION_JSON])
        response.parser([APPLICATION_JSON]) { config, resp ->
            NativeHandlers.Parsers.json(config, resp)
        }
    }
}
```